# Pidgin on Windows query

Tags: windows, pidgin, windows-vista

why is there a text entry box when I start typing with the buddylist highlighted?

Its appears to open a text entry box that when entered into and return pressed serves no purpose?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This text box is used as a quick method of searching your contacts.  Type in the first few letters of a contact's name and they will automatically be highlighted in your Buddy List.  Press enter to open a new IM tab with them.